# how to run angular 4.1 in wamp not in node server

Tags: node.js, angular, wamp

How to run an Angular 4.1 application in browser without using NodeJS as a server.
The code i have got when i commend 'npm start' it default start running in node sever .I want to run the application through wamp .

Comment: Wamp stands for Windows Apache Mysql PHP. Apache is not Node Server, and PHP is not JavaScript . So, you can keep the Windows part of the WAMP acronyme, maybe. I don't say it's not possible to do what you would like to do, but it's counterintuitive.

Comment: MEAN could be viewed as the equivalent of WAMP, but for node. However, you'd need npm to install it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply , but i want to include angularjs in .php file

Comment: sorry for these answers, I misunderstood the question. It's fairly easy. First, create a normal site on your wamp machine, just with \index.html . Then download angular, and extract the files into \javascript\ . Then follow an angular tutorial to see how to include angular js files to your page, see how to make interact the server (php files) and angular,..

Comment: can u please send me any link or example